# Plot with colours and shapes and filling to match multiple variables in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
 Op.1 Op.2 Site diet Horse ICS
 35   25    a    1     1  10
 32   31    a    1     2  10
 19   32    a    1     3  10
 17   26    a    1     4  10
 25   19    a    1     5  10
 25   17    a    1     6  10
 #... to 432 observations
```

I have done Bland-Altman plots using the following function:

```
 BAplot <- function(x,y,yAxisLim=c(-50,50),xlab="Average", ylab="Difference") {
   d <- ((x + y)/2)
   diff <- x - y        
   plot(diff ~ d,ylim=yAxisLim,xlim=c(0,60),xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab)
   abline(h=(mean(na.omit(diff))-c(-0.96,0,0.96)*sd(na.omit(diff))),lty=2)
 }
```

The plot obtained is fine. Now I am trying to give colours according to data$Site (4 levels: 0,1,2,3) and shapes according to the levels of data$ICS (6 levels: 10,11,12,13,14,15)

I wrote the following code:

```
 clr   <- c("a"="red","b"="blue","c"="green","d"="yellow")[data$Site]
 shape <- c("10"="0","11"="1","12"="2","13"="3","14"="4","15"="5")[data$ICS]
 plot.ops<-BAplot(data$Op.1,data$Op.2,xlab="(Op1 vs Op 2)/2", ylab="Op1-mean of aOp1+Op2",col=clr,pch=shape)
```

But it gives the error

```
 Error in BAplot(data$Op.1, data$Op.2, xlab = "(Op1 vs Op 2)/2", ylab = "Op1-mean of Op1+Op2",  : 
    unused arguments (col = clr, pch = shape)
```

I also tried to change shape <- c(10=0,11=1,12=2...) 1,2,3 are different shapes types in pch but it still doesn't work. Same said for clr.

What I ultimately wish to have is the plot with different colours for "site" and different shapes for "ICS".

This is meant to be something very simple but I think there might be a basic conceptual error, nevertheless I am stuck.

I also would add diet (2 levels) by using filled or emptied shapes... but can not get to that stage until I get this sorted first!

Many thanks,
M

Comment: Well, your function `BAplto` does not really accept a `col` and `pch` parameters you should add those...

Comment: Ah that was simple, it did not cross my mind that they they were necessary as I figured they would be a part of plot() within the function. Now I added them and I don't get the error, but at the same time I there is no colour or difference in shape - now all the datapoints come as empty circles rather than filled points.

Comment: My question at this point becomes if I can assign a vector to col and pch. I tried    shape <- c(0,1,2,8)[factor(data$Site)]
cls <- c("red","blue","green","yellow","purple","gray05") [factor(data$ICS)] and then put BAplot(..., col=cls,pch=shape) which create the vectors but then fails to produce a plot at all now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what made it for me in the end:

```
a<-ifelse(data$ICS==10,"a",ifelse(data$ICS==11,"b",ifelse(data$ICS==12,"c",ifelse(data$ICS==13,"d",ifelse(data$ICS==14,"e","f"))))) #ICS as characters
cls<-c(2,"orange",7,3,6,4) [factor(a)] #10-11-12-13-14-15: red,orange,yellow,green,purple,blue
b<-data$Site
shapes<-c(0,1,2,8)[factor(b)] #Square is RDC liv, Circle is RDC V, Triangle is RVC V, Star is RVC CCJ
BAplot <- function(x,y,yAxisLim=c(-50,50),xlab="Average", ylab="Difference",col=cls,pch=shapes) {
  d <- ((x + y)/2)
  diff <- x - y        
  plot(diff ~ d,ylim=yAxisLim,xlim=c(0,60),xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,col=cls,pch=shapes)
  abline(h=(mean(na.omit(diff))-c(-0.96,0,0.96)*sd(na.omit(diff))),lty=2)
}
plot.ops<-BAplot(data$Op.1,data$Op.2,xlab="(Op1 vs Op 2)/2", ylab="Op1-mean of Op1+Op2",col=cls,pch=shapes)
title(main="Bland-Altman plots of Op1 vs Op2")
legend (34,53,legend=c("RDC Liver","RDC V","RVC V","RVC CCJ"), pch=c(0,1,2,8), pt.cex=2, y.intersp=0.8) #legend for shape
legend (49,53,legend=c("10th ICS","11th ICS","12th ICS","13th ICS","14th ICS","15th ICS"), pch=22, pt.cex=2, pt.bg=c(2,"orange",7,3,6,4), y.intersp=0.6) #legend for the colours
```

Not sure why but it would not work had I written

```
shapes<-c(0,1,2,8)[factor(data$Site)]
```

it only worked if I created

```
b<-data$Site
shapes<-c(0,1,2,8)[factor(b)]
```

Anyway, sorted now!

Many thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code, and the problem is that shape is all made of `NA`.

This is due to the fact that `data$ICS` is numeric, not string.

You can use this to solve the issue (note that I removed the quotes from the number, otherwise the number themselves will be used as shapes, which is quite ugly:

```
shapes <- c("10"=0,"11"=1,"12"=2,"13"=3,"14"=4,"15"=5)[as.character(data$ICS)]
```

or, much simpler

```
shapes <- (1:5)[data$ICS-10]
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! This is what made it for me in the end!